# How to link libpqxx in MinGW?

Tags: c++, postgresql, mingw, msys, libpqxx

I am writing a C++ program and I want to use libpqxx to query a PostgreSQL database in MinGW. It's the first time I use MinGW so I am totally at a loss about how to do this. I also downoaded MSYS and followed any instructions i found but I can't figure out how to make this work. I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me a step by step guide.

EDIT: I understand that I am asking too much so I will rephrase my question. I need advice for the part of compiling libpqxx using libpq (on Windows). I just thought that having a complete guide would help in case I've done something wrong before this part.